# MYSQL retrieve data from two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a small discussion system where people can login and post a discussion. On the homepage I want to show the discussions.

First I retrieve the data for the discussions (topic, category, username, etc) from the table 'discussions'and order them by 'date_time'.

I put these values in div's that are working just how I want it. The problem I am having now is to show the avatar of the user. The avatars are stored in a table 'users' under the column 'avatar'.

So I need to retrieve the value from the column 'avatar' in the table 'users' where 'username' matches the username of the discussion.

This is the code that I have now but it's not working. I have tried different things but I am not very familiar yet with PHP so I don't really know how to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
        topic, 
        category, 
        date_time, 
        username, 
        SUBSTRING(discussion, 1, 80) AS discussion 
    FROM discussions 
    ORDER BY date_time DESC");  
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<div class="discusscolumn">
    <div>
        <p><? echo $record['category'] . ":  <b>" . $record['topic'] . "</b>"?></p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <?php
        $discussion_username=$record['username'];
        $getavatar = mysql_query("SELECT avatar, username FROM users WHERE username='$discussion_username' ");
        $avatarrecord = mysql_fetch_array($getavatar);
        echo'<span class="smallpic"><img src="user/'.$record['username'].'/'.$getavatar['avatar'].'"></span>'; 
    ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Posted by <? echo "<a href='user.php?u=".$record['username']."'>".$record['username'] ?> </a></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><br><? echo $record['discussion'] ?>&nbsp...</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><? echo $record['date_time'] ?></p>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Discuss</a></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

PS: I know I am working with mysql instead of mysqli and that I'm mixing HTML and PHP code but I just want the basics to work now.

Comment: What happens when the code is run versus what is expected? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Instead of the avatar image I get the 'image not found' icon, no errors @Qirel

Comment: Is the path displayed correctly? If you `echo` the path inside the `img src`, is it the same as the path in your directory?

Comment: Yes the path is correct. It's the same path used on other pages (for example the account page) where it does show the avatar correctly

Comment: Have you put the retrieved path into your URL to see if that displays the image correctly? It doesn't seem to be your SQL that is causing the error, more the URL is incorrect.

Comment: When I go to the url directly it shows the images correctly.. mywebsite/user/username/xxx.jpg (where xxx.jpg is the value of 'avatar' from the table 'users')

Comment: I found the problem! I echoed $getavatar['avatar'] instead of $recordavatar['avatar'].. Thanks for the help anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **img source(src)**, that you have passed as **user/username/avatar** instead of passing like this please put **url** like http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg **so that you will be getting out**. But in your case you **need to have all your user image** in some other **global storage area for eg.Amazon s3 bucket**, and you need to **get string** from **database** **construct** like **above url** and append that in **img src** inside **input tag**